# Issues with enclosing PDDoucment

Tags: java, spring-boot, pdfbox

I have implemented a program that will print data into a pdf however I am facing this issue

```
java.io.IOException: COSStream has been closed and cannot be read. Perhaps its enclosing PDDocument has been closed?
```

I know there have been similar issues posted but I could not find the solution to my problem from them. What I am doing is that I initialized two documents one of them being the main document(doc) the other for the rest of the pages and then I add to the main one(activeDocument), the service calls three different functions to add a new page one for the first page one for any pages in between, one for before the last and finally the last page.a Here is my code most of the logic can be ignored its mainly just the things relating to PDDocuments since thats where the issue lies

```
private InputStream generateCardsPDF(String cardNumber,
                                         String generationDate,
                                         StatementSummaryResTypeStatementSummaryResBody resBody,
                                         String pdf) throws IOException, ParseException {


        List<StatementSummaryResTypeStatementSummaryResBodyTransactionsTransaction> transactionList = resBody.getTransactions().getTransaction().stream().limit(50).collect(Collectors.toList());
        PDDocument doc = new PDDocument().load(getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(pdf));
        PDDocumentCatalog docCatalog = doc.getDocumentCatalog();
        PDPage page = docCatalog.getPages().get(0);
        try {
            String fullName = resBody.getStatementHeader().getAddress().getTitle() +
                    " " + resBody.getStatementHeader().getAddress().getFirstName() + " ";
            String fullAddress = "";
            if (resBody.getStatementHeader().getAddress().getMiddleName() != null) {
                fullName = fullName + resBody.getStatementHeader().getAddress().getMiddleName() + " ";
            }

            fullName = fullName + resBody.getStatementHeader().getAddress().getLastName();


            String countryAddress = resBody.getStatementHeader().getAddress().getCity() != null ? resBody.getStatementHeader().getAddress().getCity() : "";
            countryAddress += resBody.getStatementHeader().getAddress().getCountry() != null &&
                    countryAddress.length() > 0 ? ", " + resBody.getStatementHeader().getAddress().getCountry() : "";
            countryAddress += resBody.getStatementHeader().getAddress().getCountry() != null &&
                    countryAddress.length() == 0 ? resBody.getStatementHeader().getAddress().getCountry() : "";

            fullAddress += resBody.getStatementHeader().getAddress().getAddress1() + ONE_LINE;
            fullAddress += resBody.getStatementHeader().getAddress().getAddress2() != null ? resBody.getStatementHeader().getAddress().getAddress2() + ONE_LINE : "";
            fullAddress += resBody.getStatementHeader().getAddress().getAddress3() != null ? resBody.getStatementHeader().getAddress().getAddress3() + ONE_LINE : "";
            fullAddress += countryAddress;

            String header = fullName + ONE_LINE + fullAddress;
            Integer currentIndex = 0;
            Integer count = 0;
            Integer cutOff = 0;
            Integer pageNumber = 1;
            Integer numberOfPages = statementsUtils.calculateNumberOfPages(transactionList, currentIndex, cutOff, count);
            String pageOf;
            PDDocument activeDocument = new PDDocument();
            statementsUtils.setFirstPage(transactionList, resBody, doc, header, maskedCard(cardNumber), generationDate, numberOfPages);
            try {
                while (currentIndex < transactionList.size()) {
                    Boolean fourOrFive = false;
                    Boolean checkpoint = false;
                    Boolean finalPrint = false;
                    if (count == 4) {
                        checkpoint = statementsUtils.reachedCheckpoint(currentIndex, transactionList);
                        if (checkpoint) {
                            cutOff = currentIndex;
                            fourOrFive = true;
                            pageNumber++;
                            pageOf = "Page " + pageNumber.toString() + " of " + numberOfPages.toString();
                            statementsUtils.addExtraPage(doc, activeDocument, cutOff, fourOrFive, transactionList, resBody, pageOf, pdf, header, maskedCard(cardNumber), generationDate);
                            count = 0;
                        }
                    } else if (count == 5) {
                        cutOff = currentIndex;
                        fourOrFive = false;
                        pageNumber++;
                        pageOf = "Page " + pageNumber.toString() + " of " + numberOfPages.toString();
                        statementsUtils.addExtraPage(doc, activeDocument, cutOff, fourOrFive, transactionList, resBody, pageOf, pdf, header, maskedCard(cardNumber), generationDate);
                        count = 0;
                    } else if (transactionList.size() <= 2) {
                        finalPrint = true;
                    } else if (transactionList.size() - currentIndex + 1 <= 5) { // count <4? print last page or count >=4 print 4 and check homuch left
                        finalPrint = true;
                        pageNumber++;
                        pageOf = "Page " + pageNumber.toString() + " of " + numberOfPages.toString();
                        if (transactionList.size() - currentIndex + 1 == 5) {
                            statementsUtils.setPreLastPage(doc, activeDocument, currentIndex, transactionList, resBody, pageOf, pdf, header, maskedCard(cardNumber), generationDate);
                            pageNumber++;
                            pageOf = "Page " + pageNumber.toString() + " of " + numberOfPages.toString();
                            statementsUtils.setLastPage(doc, activeDocument, transactionList.size() - 1, transactionList, resBody, pageOf, pdf, header, maskedCard(cardNumber), generationDate);
                        } else {
                            statementsUtils.setLastPage(doc, activeDocument, currentIndex - count + 1, transactionList, resBody, pageOf, pdf, header, maskedCard(cardNumber), generationDate);
                        }
                    }

                    if (fourOrFive && !finalPrint)
                        currentIndex = cutOff + 1;
                    else if (finalPrint)
                        currentIndex = transactionList.size();
                    else
                        currentIndex++;

                    if (currentIndex >= 2) count++;
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                if (activeDocument != null) {
                    activeDocument.close();
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            PDPageContentStream contentStream = new PDPageContentStream(doc, page, PDPageContentStream.AppendMode.APPEND, true);
            contentStream.close();
            ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            if (doc != null) {
                doc.save(out);
                doc.close();
            }
            ByteArrayInputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(out.toByteArray());
            return in;
        }

    }



  public void setFirstPage( PDDocument doc,....){
PDAcroForm acroForm = doc.getDocumentCatalog().getAcroForm();
...
acroForm.flatten();

}

      public void setPreLastPage( PDDocument doc, PDDocument activeDocument....){
     activeDocument = new PDDocument().load(getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(pdf));
        PDDocumentCatalog docCatalog = activeDocument.getDocumentCatalog();
        PDPage p1 = docCatalog.getPages().get(0);
        PDAcroForm acroForm = docCatalog.getAcroForm();
        ...
        acroForm.flatten();
        PDPageContentStream cs = new PDPageContentStream(activeDocument, p1,PDPageContentStream.AppendMode.APPEND, true);
        cs.close();
        ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        activeDocument.save(out);
        doc.addPage(p1);
    
    }

      public void setLastPage( PDDocument doc, PDDocument activeDocument....){
     activeDocument = new PDDocument().load(getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(pdf));
        PDDocumentCatalog docCatalog = activeDocument.getDocumentCatalog();
        PDPage p1 = docCatalog.getPages().get(0);
        PDAcroForm acroForm = docCatalog.getAcroForm();
        ...
        acroForm.flatten();
        PDPageContentStream cs = new PDPageContentStream(activeDocument, p1,PDPageContentStream.AppendMode.APPEND, true);
        cs.close();
        ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        activeDocument.save(out);
        doc.addPage(p1);
    
    }

      public void addExtraPage( PDDocument doc, PDDocument activeDocument....){
     activeDocument = new PDDocument().load(getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(pdf));
        PDDocumentCatalog docCatalog = activeDocument.getDocumentCatalog();
        PDPage p1 = docCatalog.getPages().get(0);
        PDAcroForm acroForm = docCatalog.getAcroForm();
        ...
        acroForm.flatten();
        PDPageContentStream cs = new PDPageContentStream(activeDocument, p1,PDPageContentStream.AppendMode.APPEND, true);
        cs.close();
        ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        activeDocument.save(out);
        doc.addPage(p1);
    
    }
```

There is a lot more logic in these functions but I tried adding only what I thought is relevant.

I believe the issue is concerning either the content stream of one of the pdfs or the order in which I close, save etc.... but I couldn't figure out what the exact issue is so any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Just to add I have multiple pdf templates and I load the one I need depending on user input. Also I am receiving that error in an exception from my rest controller.

```
            httpServletResponse.setHeader(CONTENT_TYPE, PDF_MEDIA_TYPE);
            copy(inputStream, httpServletResponse.getOutputStream());
            httpServletResponse.flushBuffer();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.info("Failed to generate pdf. " + e.getMessage());
            throw new ExceptionCustom(e.getMessage(), e);
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Three errors are in `setPreLastPage`, `setLastPage`, and `addExtraPage`: in each of these methods you load a new `PDDocument` in the respective local variable `activeDocument`,  take a page from it and add it to the same `PDDocument doc`, and then drop all references to that `PDDocument` in `activeDocument` when leaving the respective method.

Dropping all references allows the garbage collection to pick these `PDDocument` instances up and close and remove them. This pulls away the data underneath the pages copied into the `PDDocument doc`, resulting in the error you observe when trying to save `doc`.

To prevent this either clone the page objects into `doc` before adding them or keep all these temporary documents open until you save `doc`.

Comment: Regarding cloning or closing which method would you recommend and can you point me to some references? I have read up a bit about cloning but not sure if I am going the right way about it this is what I have implemented so far


        ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        activeDocument.save(out);
        PDPage newPage = new PDPage(p1.getCOSObject());
        PDFCloneUtility cloner = new PDFCloneUtility(doc);
        doc.addPage(newPage);
        cloner.cloneMerge(p1, newPage);

Comment: The easiest way would be to keep the temporary `PDDocument` instances by collecting them in some collection which you can forward to the methods as an extra parameter and only closing all those objects after `doc.save(out)`. The disadvantage would be larger resource use. I don't have real hands-on experience with the cloning approach, I merely know that it should work in principle and that it should be less resource-hungry. The code in your comment feels wrong, though.

Comment: Avoid using PDFCloneUtility. This will be removed from public use in 3.0 because too many people were misusing it.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up Tilman. Regarding the second approach how am I supposed to stop the temporary documents from being closed when leaving the methods I am calling? From my understanding though I should return each temporary document and store it in a list somewhere and then close all those documents one by one once I save the original document

Comment: The above worked. I had each of the methods return the document after it was done and stored that document in a list and then I closed each of the documents after saving the original one. I will mark this as the answer thank you for the help

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone is curious of the actual implementation of the solution I created an empty list.

```
List<PDDocument> activeDocuments = new ArrayList<PDDocument>();
```

And then everytime I called one of the methods I returned the document and stored it inside of the list and then closed them all at the end after I saved the original document.

```
  while (currentIndex < transactionList.size()) {
                    Boolean fourOrFive = false;
                    Boolean checkpoint = false;
                    Boolean finalPrint = false;
                    if (count == 4) {
                        checkpoint = statementsUtils.reachedCheckpoint(currentIndex, transactionList);
                        if (checkpoint) {
                            cutOff = currentIndex;
                            fourOrFive = true;
                            pageNumber++;
                            pageOf = "Page " + pageNumber.toString() + " of " + numberOfPages.toString();
                            activeDocuments.add(statementsUtils.addExtraPage(doc, activeDocument, cutOff, fourOrFive, transactionList, resBody, pageOf, pdf, header, maskedCard(cardNumber), generationDate));
                            count = 0;
                        }
                    } else if (count == 5) {
                        cutOff = currentIndex;
                        fourOrFive = false;
                        pageNumber++;
                        pageOf = "Page " + pageNumber.toString() + " of " + numberOfPages.toString();
                        activeDocuments.add(statementsUtils.addExtraPage(doc, activeDocument, cutOff, fourOrFive, transactionList, resBody, pageOf, pdf, header, maskedCard(cardNumber), generationDate));
                        count = 0;
                    } else if (transactionList.size() <= 2) {
                        finalPrint = true;
                    } else if (transactionList.size() - currentIndex + 1 <= 5) { // count <4? print last page or count >=4 print 4 and check homuch left
                        finalPrint = true;
                        pageNumber++;
                        pageOf = "Page " + pageNumber.toString() + " of " + numberOfPages.toString();
                        if (transactionList.size() - currentIndex + 1 == 5) {
                            activeDocuments.add(statementsUtils.setPreLastPage(doc, activeDocument, currentIndex, transactionList, resBody, pageOf, pdf, header, maskedCard(cardNumber), generationDate));
                            pageNumber++;
                            pageOf = "Page " + pageNumber.toString() + " of " + numberOfPages.toString();
                            activeDocuments.add(statementsUtils.setLastPage(doc, activeDocument, transactionList.size() - 1, transactionList, resBody, pageOf, pdf, header, maskedCard(cardNumber), generationDate));
                        } else {
                            activeDocuments.add(statementsUtils.setLastPage(doc, activeDocument, currentIndex - count + 1, transactionList, resBody, pageOf, pdf, header, maskedCard(cardNumber), generationDate));
                        }
                    }

                    if (fourOrFive && !finalPrint)
                        currentIndex = cutOff + 1;
                    else if (finalPrint)
                        currentIndex = transactionList.size();
                    else
                        currentIndex++;

                    if (currentIndex >= 2) count++;
                }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            PDPageContentStream contentStream = new PDPageContentStream(doc, page, PDPageContentStream.AppendMode.APPEND, true);
            contentStream.close();
            ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            if (doc != null) {
                doc.save(out);
                doc.close();
            }
            for (PDDocument a : activeDocuments)
                a.close();

            if (activeDocument != null) {
                activeDocument.close();
            }
            ByteArrayInputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(out.toByteArray());
            return in;
        }
```